# Array transformation in puppet for eventual joining and inclusion in a command

Tags: arrays, iteration, puppet

This sounds trivial, but I cant wrap my head around what I need to do! I have:

```
$nodes = ["node1", "node2", "node3"]
```

I want to end up with this:

```
$somestring = "node1=http://node1:2380,node2=http://node2:2380,node3=http://node3:2380"
```

I have tried this:

```
 $nodes = ['node1','node2','node3']
 $nodes2 = $nodes
 $merged = concat($nodes, $nodes2)
 $sorted = sort($merged)
 $test = $sorted.reduce |$memo, $value | {
   "${memo} = http://$value:2380,"
 }
 notify {"nodelist is $test":}
```

But gives me:

```
node1=http://node1:2380,=http://node2:2380,=http://node2:2380,=http://node3:2380,=http://node3:2380,
```

The idea is that in the likely event of needing to add a node to this cluster, I can just add an entry to the array, once I have my node ready.

Comment: From an architecture perspective, this is not really the best way to go about this. From an implementation perspective, the pitfall here is using `reduce` as the lambda iterator. If you are not so concerned with storing the return, then you can use `each`. If you are, then `map` combined with `with` will get you to your goal. I can write up an answer if this is confusing.

Comment: @MattSchuchard. Thanks & Yes please!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your naming conventions, we begin with the array:

```
$nodes = ['node1', 'node2', 'node3']
```

We then need to insert the string twice within each element of the array with the `map` lambda iterator (https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#map):

```
$somearray = $nodes.map |$node| {
  "${node}=http://${node}:2380"
}
# $somearray = ['node1=http://node1:2380', 'node2=http://node2:2380', 'node3=http://node3:2380']
```

At this point, we could do a Tuple/Array to String conversion (https://puppet.com/docs/puppet/5.5/function.html#array--tuple-to-string), but this would require complicated flags for delimiter notation and a possible regular expression substitution afterward. Much easier would be to use `join` from puppetlabs-stdlib, which is present in almost every Puppet environment (https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/stdlib#join):

```
$somestring = join($somearray, ',')
# $somestring = 'node1=http://node1:2380,node2=http://node2:2380,node3=http://node3:2380'
```

Fun fact: `split` is a Puppet intrinsic function but `join` requires stdlib. Not sure how that happened.